# Как сделать, чтобы сайт был в интернете?

Tags: хостинг, домен

Вот я сделал сайт, все протестил и т.п. Что дальше, объясните новичку, пожалуйста?
Я живу в Украине и хочу, чтобы сайт был .ru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

есть система бесплатных доменов/сайтов [unet](http://unet.com).

Там можно сделать свой сайт, и бесплатный домен получить(домен в роде вашсайт.at.ua)
там в роде и .ru домены есть...
а свой собственный домен можно зарегистрировать за деньги.
есть такие провайдеры, которые предоставляют и хостинг сайта, и доменное имя, в сумме - примерно 10 грн. в месяц.

Answer (score 4):

1. Регистрируете доменное имя у любого регистратора (reg.ru и т.п.)
2. Для простого сайта регистрируетесь на narod.ru для сложного - покупаете хостинг (тот же reg.ru)
3. Прописываете записи DNS так, чтобы доменное имя указывало на ip сервера
4. Заливаете файлы сайта на сервер хостинга

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но narod.ru это вообще край... **www.ayola.net** для начала самое оно!

Comment: Заливаете файлы сайта на сервер хостинга
А если что-то захочется поменять, что тогда меняешь у себя, потом опять заливать на хостинг?

Comment: @Palmervan Почему? Для статического сайта-визитки, где ничего, кроме HTML и javascript нет, вполне приемлимо.

Comment: @ZoZexZero Да, всякий раз, как локально меняете, надо синхронизироваться.

Answer (score 1):

Земляк)

> и хочу, что-бы сайт был .ru

Да какой угодно! Ограничений в доменных зонах нет! Есть, но это уже юридическая часть, вопроса. Идем на любой хостинг, покупаем хостинг с доменом в той зоне, в которой хотим. В вашем случае .ru! Если хостер и регистратор доменов один, то сайт заработает сразу, если хостер и регистратор разные, то прийдется подождать пока обновлятся [DNS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS).

Ну и в панели управления хостингом, создаем FTP аккаунты, базы данных и пользователей к ним и т.д.

В интернете информации по этому поводу море, все прийдет с опытом! Главное искать, Гугль и Яшу для этого и придумали!)